# Full outer merge of more than two tables in ms sql server to prepare desired table as shown in the example

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables as shown below.

t1:

```
id     runs
001    1200
020    600
123    1500
```

t2:

```
id     wickets
008    4
030    7
123    0
020    6
```

t3:

```
id     catches
007    4
030    
123    2
040    6
```

I would like to perform FULL OUTER JOIN of all the three tables and prepare the as shown below.

Expected output:

```
id     runs      wickets     catches
001    1200
020    600       6
123    1500      0           2
008              4
030              7
007                          4
040                          6
```

I tried below code and did not works.

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
FULL OUTER JOIN t2.id = t3.id
```

I did the same using pandas using following code and it worked well.

```
from functools import reduce
dfl=[t1, t2, t3]
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['id'],
                                            how='outer'), dfl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the expected columns you want to obtain from each table:

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.id,t2.id, t3.id), t1.runs, t2.wickets, t3.catches
FROM  t1
FULL OUTER JOIN  t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
FULL OUTER JOIN  t3 ON COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) = t3.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **UNION ALL** in a sub-query and then **GROUP BY**.
This would give you zeros where there is no value. If this is a problem we could modify the presentation.
If you have another table with all the players we could us **LEFT JOIN** onto the three tables with
`WHERE runs <>'' OR wickets <> '' OR catches <> ''`

```
select
sum(runs) "runs",
sum(wickets) "wickets",
sum(catches) "catches) 
from(
select id, runs, 0 wickets, 0 catches from t1
  union all
select id, 0, wickets,0 from t2
  union all
select id, 0,0, catches from t3
)
group by id,
order by id;
```